# Launching Minecraft via Python subprocess doesn't work

Tags: java, python, windows, cmd, minecraft

Today I've tried to start the Minecraft client via command line on Windows 7. It works! With this code:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives" -cp "%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.3\authlib-1.3.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.10.Final\netty-all-4.0.10.Final.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\java3d\vecmath\1.3.1\vecmath-1.3.1.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\trove4j\trove4j\3.0.3\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.5\jopt-simple-4.5.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\15.0\guava-15.0.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.0\lwjgl-2.9.0.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.0\lwjgl_util-2.9.0.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10.jar" net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username [username] --version 1.7.10 --gameDir C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Roaming\.minec~1 --assetsDir C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Roaming\.minec~1\assets --accessToken [accessToken] --uuid [uuid] --userProperties {} --userType mojang
```

A littlebit long, but it works fine if you set the username, uuid and accessToken.

Now I want to create a little Minecraft launcher with Python (little gui and so on), and I know that I can call a command with subprocess and Popen.

So I've tried Popen:

```
import subprocess

# sc = start command
sc = ['java', '-Xmx1024M', '-Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\versions\\1.7.10\\1.7.10-natives"', '-cp', '"%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\log4j-api\\2.0-beta9\\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\log4j-core\\2.0-beta9\\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\ibm\\icu\\icu4j-core-mojang\\51.2\\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\mojang\\authlib\\1.3\\authlib-1.3.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\io\\netty\\netty-all\\4.0.10.Final\\netty-all-4.0.10.Final.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\java3d\\vecmath\\1.3.1\\vecmath-1.3.1.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\net\\sf\\trove4j\\trove4j\\3.0.3\\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\net\\sf\\jopt-simple\\jopt-simple\\4.5\\jopt-simple-4.5.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\codecjorbis\\20101023\\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\codecwav\\20101023\\codecwav-20101023.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\librarylwjglopenal\\20100824\\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\libraryjavasound\\20101123\\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\soundsystem\\20120107\\soundsystem-20120107.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\google\\guava\\guava\\15.0\\guava-15.0.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\org\\apache\\commons\\commons-lang3\\3.1\\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\commons-io\\commons-io\\2.4\\commons-io-2.4.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\net\\java\\jinput\\jinput\\2.0.5\\jinput-2.0.5.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\net\\java\\jinput\\jinput-platform\\2.0.5\\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\net\\java\\jutils\\jutils\\1.0.0\\jutils-1.0.0.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\google\\code\\gson\\gson\\2.2.4\\gson-2.2.4.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\org\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\2.9.0\\lwjgl-2.9.0.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\org\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\lwjgl_util\\2.9.0\\lwjgl_util-2.9.0.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\versions\\1.7.10\\1.7.10.jar"', 'net.minecraft.client.main.Main', '--username', '[username]', '--version', '1.7.10', '--gameDir', 'C:\\Users\\Jon\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft', '--assetsDir C:\\Users\\Jon\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\assets', '--accessToken', '[accessToken]', '--uuid', '[uuid]', '--userProperties', '{}', '--userType', 'mojang']
p = subprocess.Popen(sc, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
o = p.stdout.readline()
e = p.stderr.readline()
if o:
    print o
if e:
    print e
if o or e:
    pass
else:
    break
```

It doesn't work because an error occures:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager

    at bao.<clinit>(SourceFile:84)

    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:72)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager


    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

    ... 2 more
```

In the normal command line the command works fine without any problems, but only in Python there is a problem. Ok, after a bit of thinking I realise that I can "pipe" cmd.exe and the java command + arguments.

So I've tried it, too:

```
import subprocess

### as you can see, I've tried to replace the %appdata%-placeholder too

# start command
sc = ['java', '-Xmx1024M', '-Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\versions\\1.7.10\\1.7.10-natives"', '-cp', '"%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\log4j-api\\2.0-beta9\\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\log4j-core\\2.0-beta9\\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\ibm\\icu\\icu4j-core-mojang\\51.2\\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\mojang\\authlib\\1.3\\authlib-1.3.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\io\\netty\\netty-all\\4.0.10.Final\\netty-all-4.0.10.Final.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\java3d\\vecmath\\1.3.1\\vecmath-1.3.1.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\net\\sf\\trove4j\\trove4j\\3.0.3\\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\net\\sf\\jopt-simple\\jopt-simple\\4.5\\jopt-simple-4.5.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\codecjorbis\\20101023\\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\codecwav\\20101023\\codecwav-20101023.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\librarylwjglopenal\\20100824\\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\libraryjavasound\\20101123\\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\soundsystem\\20120107\\soundsystem-20120107.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\google\\guava\\guava\\15.0\\guava-15.0.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\org\\apache\\commons\\commons-lang3\\3.1\\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\commons-io\\commons-io\\2.4\\commons-io-2.4.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\net\\java\\jinput\\jinput\\2.0.5\\jinput-2.0.5.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\net\\java\\jinput\\jinput-platform\\2.0.5\\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\net\\java\\jutils\\jutils\\1.0.0\\jutils-1.0.0.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\google\\code\\gson\\gson\\2.2.4\\gson-2.2.4.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\org\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\2.9.0\\lwjgl-2.9.0.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\org\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\lwjgl_util\\2.9.0\\lwjgl_util-2.9.0.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\versions\\1.7.10\\1.7.10.jar"', 'net.minecraft.client.main.Main', '--username', 'Microskype', '--version', '1.7.10', '--gameDir', 'C:\\Users\\Jon\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft', '--assetsDir C:\\Users\\Jon\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\assets', '--accessToken', '40b9d172b3fe4e3486e33a67ca3db075', '--uuid', 'e457b026-2e68-40b6-b38d-fcb3645ba318', '--userProperties', '{}', '--userType', 'mojang']
# new start command starting with cmd.exe and /C to pipe cmd.exe and the java command + parameters
nsc = ["cmd.exe", "/C"]

for one in sc:
    one = one.replace('%APPDATA%', 'C:\\Users\\Jon\\AppData\\Roaming')
    one = one.replace('%appdata%', 'C:\\Users\\Jon\\AppData\\Roaming')
    nsc.append(one)

p = subprocess.Popen(nsc, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    o = p.stdout.readline()
    e = p.stderr.readline()
    if o:
        print o
    if e:
        print e
    if o or e:
        pass
    else:
        break
```

Then I've tried to use the whole Java path instead of java, but than I get `WindowsError: [Error 5] Access denied`. Is the command to long? :D

I think the problem is Windows, but there must be a way to solve the problem.
Have you any ideas?

Regards,
Jonniboy

Comment: Windows command line is limited to 1024 characters.

Comment: @tdelaney I thought it to, but how can I solve the problem without breaking the limits?

Comment: try putting the -cp string in the CLASSPATH environment variable instead. `env = os.environ.copy();env['CLASSPATH']="the class path string";Popen(..., env=env)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a little workaround. It was a long time ago, but here is my messy workaround:

I created a .bat file with the command in a temporary folder. Now I could start Minecraft with the long command version.

Don't know securely, but I think that the `shell=True` extension didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try modifying your first version by adding `shell=True` to the `Popen` constructor?

```
import subprocess

# sc = start command
sc = ['java', '-Xmx1024M', '-Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\versions\\1.7.10\\1.7.10-natives"', '-cp', '"%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\log4j-api\\2.0-beta9\\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\log4j-core\\2.0-beta9\\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\ibm\\icu\\icu4j-core-mojang\\51.2\\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\mojang\\authlib\\1.3\\authlib-1.3.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\io\\netty\\netty-all\\4.0.10.Final\\netty-all-4.0.10.Final.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\java3d\\vecmath\\1.3.1\\vecmath-1.3.1.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\net\\sf\\trove4j\\trove4j\\3.0.3\\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\net\\sf\\jopt-simple\\jopt-simple\\4.5\\jopt-simple-4.5.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\codecjorbis\\20101023\\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\codecwav\\20101023\\codecwav-20101023.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\librarylwjglopenal\\20100824\\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\libraryjavasound\\20101123\\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\paulscode\\soundsystem\\20120107\\soundsystem-20120107.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\google\\guava\\guava\\15.0\\guava-15.0.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\org\\apache\\commons\\commons-lang3\\3.1\\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\commons-io\\commons-io\\2.4\\commons-io-2.4.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\net\\java\\jinput\\jinput\\2.0.5\\jinput-2.0.5.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\net\\java\\jinput\\jinput-platform\\2.0.5\\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\net\\java\\jutils\\jutils\\1.0.0\\jutils-1.0.0.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\com\\google\\code\\gson\\gson\\2.2.4\\gson-2.2.4.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\org\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\2.9.0\\lwjgl-2.9.0.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\libraries\\org\\lwjgl\\lwjgl\\lwjgl_util\\2.9.0\\lwjgl_util-2.9.0.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\versions\\1.7.10\\1.7.10.jar"', 'net.minecraft.client.main.Main', '--username', '[username]', '--version', '1.7.10', '--gameDir', 'C:\\Users\\Jon\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft', '--assetsDir C:\\Users\\Jon\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\assets', '--accessToken', '[accessToken]', '--uuid', '[uuid]', '--userProperties', '{}', '--userType', 'mojang']
p = subprocess.Popen(sc, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
while True:
    o = p.stdout.readline()
    e = p.stderr.readline()
    if o:
        print o
    if e:
        print e
    if o or e:
        pass
    else:
        break
```